# Alternate image in a imageview of screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, android-imageview

I have two images in my drawable folder and I desire to alternate the two images in my view every x time.
I try to use a Asynctask but don't work and I can't found the solution.

My xml Code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imatge"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:src="@drawable/hdtitol2" />
```

I call the class with:

```
new ModifyImage().execute(null,null,null);
```

The main class contains de class with async code

```
public class ModifyImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ImageView img= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageload);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i = 0;
        boolean opt = true;
        boolean exit = false;
        while(!exit){
            if(i == 1000){
                i = 0;
                if(!opt){
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackhdtitol2);
                    opt =true;
                }else{
                    opt = false;
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.hdtitol2);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void i){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found a possible solution descarting all de java code that I had about this problem.

The solution that I found is to create a new class

```
public class RepeatingThread implements Runnable {

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public RepeatingThread() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageload);

        if(img.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE ){
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);       
    }
}
```

And the code in the function on create:

```
final Thread t = new Thread(new RepeatingThread());
    t.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Integer tag = (Integer) img.getTag();
        if(tag == R.drawable.blackhdtitol2){
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackhdtitol2);
                img.setTag(R.drawable.blackhdtitol2);
            }else{
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.hdtitol2);
                img.setTag(R.drawable.hdtitol2);
            }
    }
}, 60*1000);
```